# Firebug shows font change in the console on either the use of , or + to concatonate strings

Tags: javascript, firebug, string-concatenation

I have come across an interesting effect on firebug, when using the `+` operator or the `,` operator to concatonate strings and then print something to the console the font changes based on which operator you used.

In this case the font for the word **Harry** changes:

[image]

Why does this happen? Isn't the comma operator used for concatonation as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No the comma is not used for concatenation. `console.log` will independently log each of its arguments to the same line on the console but if you separate arguments with commas, they will not be concatenated. The `+` operator will concatenate them. For example:

```
console.log('hello', {foo: 'bar'}); //=> 'hello', {foo: 'bar'}

console.log('hello' + {foo: 'bar'}); //=> 'hello[object Object]'
```

Using the `+` operator, JavaScript will attempt to call `.toString` on the object in order to concatenate it onto the previous string. Using the comma, each piece is considered its own argument passed to `console.log` which then logs each one.

As far as why firebug changes the font, I couldn't say. What I *can* say is that it has nothing to do with the actual JavaScript in your application.

Comment: It changes the font because it's representing different things, the `,` one is an `[object]` the `+` is (as you say) a `string`. So the different font's represent this.

Comment: Liam, the font change doesn't happen in Chrome dev tools so I'm not sure the type really matters. If the argument for `who` is a string, it wouldn't have to do any type coercion anyway. The point is, this a Firebug quirk and not a JavaScript quirk.

Comment: Yes, we're saying the same thing. This is a feature of firebug

Comment: And the bug got obviously fixed by Simon right after posting his comment. :-) So in Firebug 2.0 this should be displayed as expected.